# How to replicate this canvas effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have to replicate the effect showed when you press "play" button in **[this page](http://www.google.it/enterprise/solutions.html)**,
how can I do it?

Comment: Really, you have to replicate animations created by Google, that aren't really in a canvas, and you have no idea where to begin. Maybe you should start smaller ?

Comment: These are all custom made dom animations. You could use an animation library like TweenJS, Raphael, jQuery's animation, etc... Also look into CSS3 transitions and animation effects.

Comment: Agreed. CSS3 animations and transformations would be the simplest solution.  You could do it with Canvas+transforms, but why bother learning all about the canvas when CSS3 gives a simpler solution.

Comment: thank you for yours aswers! I just want to know what skills I need to make this solution

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not provide any code and relies on a dead link to describe a needed feature.